# how to focus the web page to a defined position with out using # , Codeigniter , Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

hi i am using `codeigniter` and `jquery`  .

i am using this code to focus the page to a defined location (here , a div).

```
    jQuery(function() {

      var profile_url = "<?php echo $widgets['basic_info_widget']['prof_url']; ?>";
        if(((window.location+"/") != (baseurl+profile_url)) && (window.location != (baseurl+profile_url))) {
            location.hash = '#menu';        
        }   
    });
```

by this i am focusing the page to `<div id='menu'></div>`

```
location.hash = '#menu'
```

but the thing is when the script runs `#menu` is added after the url

```
http://example.com#menu


*can i fous this div without adding #menu at the end of the url .
```

like

```
 http://example.com
```

please help . thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W8vdu/)**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#second_div").offset().top }, 2000);
   });​
```

Using [**scrollTop**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: giving an error to me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Comment: i have posted my code in the question , that is the only script

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya i don't understand, your script sets focus to div based on hash from url and you don't want to use that. Did you get error from my code??

Comment: i want know is there a better way . your code gives the error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya ok..can you show how you implemented this code